# How do you use shallow_array_adaptor

Tags: c++, pointers, boost

I'm trying to interface with software that just uses raw pointers for holding data.
I feel pretty confident that I can avoid the issues with using `shallow_array_adaptor` 
if I make the wrapping vector instances `const` even though the documentation for `shallow_array_adaptor` claims that it is "very dangerous!".

I'd like to do things like:

```
using namespace boost::numeric::ublas
void f(vector<double>& acc, double* arr){ 
    // assume acc is already correctly sized, and arr is correctly allocated

   // this syntax is not correct, I'm pretty sure I'll have to construct
   // the instance of shallow_array_adaptor, but don't know how  to
   // get it to the vector's constructor 
   const vector< double , shallow_array_adaptor< double > > view( arr );

    acc+=view; // by wrapping the raw pointer, I get to use nice syntax here.
}
```

without having to copy the values stored in `arr`.

I'm not sure what I have to do to construct the vector such that it uses
the given pointer as it's storage.

Comment: Arrays and iterators behave the same. Use `view.insert(arr, arr+size);`